# How To Installation Install dependencies For a demo in Codrops

Tags: npm, npm-install

I found this site which provides tutorials on Front End Development
And I wanted to start learning, after downloading the source code, I was faced with this problem of launching the HTML file of the web page, I searched and I found that I need to install the npm, I tried everything but in vain,
any help to solve this "npm-start" "npm run build" problem
thank you in advance.
Codrops Website: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2021/01/26/twisted-colorful-spheres-with-three-js/
Project in Github: https://github.com/codrops/WebGLBlobs/

Comment: Node Package Manager(NPM); node.js(https://nodejs.org/) is what you are looking for. Installing node.js will include npm. If you are new, the 14.15.5LTS node.js version is what I would recommend

Answer (score 1):

1. Download node.js & install it (https://nodejs.org/).
2. Download the needed project from Codrops Website & extract it.
3. Using terminal and type cd/path of your project.
4. Then run the commands as mentioned in the github ("npm-start" "npm
   run build")
5. Page will be opened in a localhost server after the command "npm
   start"